# How to insert FeedItem from Apex Email Service and set the Network ID?

Tags: apex, chatter, apex-email-service, feeditem

## Setup

- External Community
- Chatter Group in External Community
- Apex Email Service trying to insert FeedItem related to Chatter Group

## Sample Code

```
FeedItem fi = new FeedItem(
    parentId = 'chatter group id in external community',
    body = 'Hello World'
);

insert fi;
```

The above code snippet **fails** when ran from Apex Email Service or Developer Console with error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: [].

If I change the **parentId** to be 'chatter group id in internal community' then it works beautifully. But when it's a group that belongs to an external community then error.

I know that in Apex there is the [ConnectApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm) and it has various `postFeedElement( communityId, ... )` methods that let you specify the `CommunityId`. But my requirement is that I need to set the **FeedItem.CreatedById** to be someone other than the context user for my open source project [Chatter Bot for Feeds](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/salesforce-chatter-bot-feeds).

The ConnectApi does not let you specify the author it instead defaults to the context user. Hence why I'm trying to do this with FeedItem and DML directly via a context user with "Insert System Field Values for Chatter Feeds" permission so that I can set the author of the post to whomever I want.

This concept works great in the internal community, but failing when the apex code tries to insert FeedItem whose parent is a group that belongs to a external community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, figured it out thanks to [Neil Hayek](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=00530000003SpRm&tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformFeed) of Salesforce. Answer is super simple!

> Set the **community id** in the `FeedItem.NetworkScope` field.

```
FeedItem fi = new FeedItem(
    parentId = 'chatter group id in external community',
    body = 'Hello World',
    networkScope = '<community id>' // e.g. 0DB0a000000PBDHGA4
);

insert fi;
```

I completely missed this and was looking for `NetworkId` field which doesn't exist. Doh!

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm

[image]

Comment: Ah I never clicked into this question and just assumed you were already setting this field.

Comment: I appreciate you thought I was smart enough to have known about that field and to have found it. I feel uber sheepish on this miss. But glad its solved!

Comment: The SOAP API Developer Guide is your friend. :)